# Creating lock so two users don't create account with the same username

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I am using the Express server with Node.js and am concerned about concurrency and preventing users from creating accounts with the same username at the same time. From my underatanding, despite the fact that the primary Node.js runtime is single-threaded, it may still be possible for one function to begin while another one has yet to complete.
One option is to create a lock on an external source like Redis, and use that to control concurrency - however my question is - is there a robust way to control this in native JavaScript? For example, is a certain level of nested functions basically going to guarantee that a new request won't initiate a certain call before another completes (I doubt it).

To be more specific - I am using MongoDB with Mongoose. There should be a unique list of users in memory using Mongoose schemas. So what could happen:

(1) new user registers with username A

(2) node.js compares A with indexed list of users, and finds that A is indeed a new username

(3) node.js makes a DB call to add A to list

(4)before (3) finishes a *new* user registers with username A...node.js compares A with the username index and it looks unique so it sends an insert to the DB

the problem seems real. My guess is that best way to solve it is an external lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way of solving this is with a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) on the corresponding mongo collection. This will prevent any inserts or updates that would cause duplicate values (Note that this is enforced by the mongodb server, not mongoose).

I'm not familiar with mongoose, but it would seem that when you tell it that an attribute is unique it creates the corresponding unique index.

Comment: yeah mongoose does have a 'unique' property on its schema fields; I hope that with this provision that mongoose behaves the way you have just described but I haven't verified that yet

Answer (score 2):

As you suspect, though node.js is single threaded, as soon as your code engages in any asynchronous operations (like any database operation), there will be an opportunity during that async operation for another request to start processing.  So, you could indeed get two (or more) conflicting operations in flight at the same time.

There are a few main approaches here.

1. **Database.** Let the database where userIDs are being created and stored enforce uniqueness.
2. **Serialize.** Serialize all possibly conflicting operations.
3. **Inflight Control.** Keep your own in-memory list of "inflight" usernames.

I'll describe a bit more about each one.

**Database.**  Since the database itself is the ultimate record of usernames, it is sometimes simplest to just let it tell the second request that tries to create a username that it can't create that username because it already exists.  When you do it this way, you just let the first request in win and any subsequent ones just get an error because the user name already exists.  While you might not use this as the only protection since it's always better to pre-flight and let the user know before they've submitted a new username that it is already in use, it can be your backstop in cases of concurrency.

The method you describe in your steps 1), 2) and 3) is a never a good way to do database operations because of the concurrency issues that you suspect.  If the database can be changed between your steps and that will invalidate your logic or cause you to do the wrong database operation, then the logic has to change.

Instead, you want to create an atomic operation that will succeed or fail.  So, you'd like to create the new proposed userID in the database.  If it succeeds in creating a new userID, then you're good, it must have been unique and it's now been created on behalf of this request.  There is no concurrency issue there.  If the userID already exists, then the create operation should just fail.  You don't want to test the userID and then decide to create it because that creates the concurrency window.  Design your database operations to be entirely atomic.  One database operation that either succeeds or fails.  Then you're letting the database handle any momentary locking and letting it do the hard work.

**Serialize Operations.**  You could implement your own traffic flow that allows only one request at a time to your database to create a new user.  This would make any other requests that come along wait for the request in process to finish.  This is less than ideal from a scalability and throughput point of view, but it is simple in concept.

**Manual Inflight Control.**  Assuming you are not running clustered servers so there's only one web server creating accounts in your database, you could keep an in-memory data structure for any username that is in the process of being created.  When any database request comes along to create a username, you can first check your in-memory datastructure to see if a request is already in process to create this username.  If so, you reject the new request.

---

Since the authoritative source of usernames is the database and it already has to have its own concurrency controls, my preference would be to just let the database tell a 2nd request to create username yyy that the username already exists and let that error percolate back to the end user.  This approach has no edge cases and the best performance profile.  You can still implement a pre-flight check to give the user the best and most immediate feedback on a username that already exists, but use the database as your backstop in case of a concurrency conflict.

Note, that if you implement it this way, you will have to make sure that your error handling path is clean in both the server and the client.  The server will have to not let an account get partially created and then err out and leave it in a bad state and the client will have to know how to properly display that error condition and what state to leave the user in.

Comment: jfriend00, thanks. thinking about what you said. i think the most scalable solution is actually to use a lock using an external database like Redis. if you have 10 web servers and they all could write to the database, the only way for them to all talk to each would be through a single resource. in other words, for one web server, your in flight control idea where there is a temporary store of in process new user requests would be more performant. but if you have 10 servers they all can't have that in memory store because they have share the info. what do you think?

Comment: @AlexMills - but talking to a central redis is itself is an async process with it's own concurrency issues.  So you can't do your steps 1, 2, 3 with redis either and not have concurrency issues.  Why not just try to create in the database and if the item already exists, the create will fail?  There is no concurrency issue with that, no matter how many servers you have.

Comment: yeah I am beginning to think you're right. the problem started because using Mongoose they have indexes of unique values in memory. but that actually creates a bigger problem. you're going to have have to go to the database or wait. might as well go to the DB and just try it. however, like you say, that is fail or succeed, no waiting for an opening. so for user registration it might be ok to say, sorry, you fail. but for other processes, I supposed fail is not ok, and we just need to increment a value, waiting for a lock to open up.

Comment: Of course, we could just give people user names like A2 or A3 or A4, using incrementation for uniqueness but I don't think users would like that so much.

Comment: and btw, distributed locks with Redis are there to solve concurrency issues- they aren't just kicking the can further down the road and they don't open up other concurrency issues... I highly recommend looking into it http://redis.io/topics/distlock

Comment: with node, try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redis-warlock I have used it and it seems to work

Comment: " So you can't do your steps 1, 2, 3 with redis either and not have concurrency issues." the way you do this is: each node process wants to write a username to the database, but we want to limit it to one at a time. so we force each node process to acquire a lock on a redis key before being allowed to write to the DB. only one process can have the lock at a time.

Comment: @AlexMills - making database operations acquire a redis lock when they did not need to do so will absolutely kill your system performance.  You will be turning a system capable of doing many requests at the same time into one that can only do one at a time.  I still don't understand why you don't just let the DB do all the work for you since it already has concurrency control over two processes trying to create the same thing.  If a create fails because it already exists, you have your answer.  If the create succeeds, you have your answer.  No concurrency issue.  No other locks needed.

Comment: @AlexMills - if your database can't do an atomic create and just return success or fail, then it's time for a new DB.  This is a very fundamental DB operation.  It sounds more to me like you're convinced you want to implement your own lock so you're looking for that solution.  Since the only problem you've described so far does not sound like it would need an external lock, I don't see why you're trying to implement one.  But, if you're going to implement a lock no matter what, I'll get out of the way.

Comment: i see what you are saying, I basically agree, I want to avoid the redis lock!!

Comment: partially, I am just bemused about the 'unique' modifier/property on mongoose database models...seems like it introduces the problem I am referring to by keeping a collection of unique database objects in memory. perhaps, if mongoose is more sophisticated than I think it is, it takes care of this problem, but i doubt it

Answer (score 2):

You could just create a list of reserved or pending names.

```
var pendingNames = [];
```

When User A wants to register with the username "Batman", you will first check if the name itself is taken or not.

If the name is not taken, you will check whether or not the name in the pending names list.

```
var name = "Batman";
if(pendingNames.indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    //abort the registration
}

// if its not in the pending list, simply add it to it
pendingNames.push(name.toLowerCase());
```

And then after the write was successful or failed, remove the name from the pending list.

There are other way too but I found this to be the fastest to quickly validate if a name can be registered or not.

Comment: thanks. this works for one web server but what about 2 or more?

Comment: In that case you would probably have to set a unique key for the username so it throws an error when attempting to create another account with that name. Which would be fine too, because registrations at the same time with the same name happen so rarely that it won't scratch the performance at all. Or you route all registrations to an account server.